# Swift Protocol Constraints Relationship

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to create/compose a protocol relationship like this:

Considere a protocol HasAction, that needs an "enum: String" like so

```swift
protocol HasActions<ChoiceEnum> {
    associatedtype ChoiceEnum: RawRepresentable where ChoiceEnum.RawValue: StringProtocol
    func action(_ choice: ChoiceEnum)
}
```

Now the "concrete" Foo Action protocol would be defined as:

```swift
enum ActionsFooEnum: String { case foo, fooo, foooo }

protocol HasFooAction: HasActions<ActionsFooEnum> {}
// or?
protocol HasFooAction2: HasActions where ChoiceEnum == ActionsFooEnum {}
// or?
typealias HasFooAction3 = HasActions<ActionsFooEnum>
```

At this point, an object implementing `HasFooAction` is capable of knowing what enum can be found in `action(...)`

Now, let's define a generic User protocol like so-ish

```swift
protocol User<ChoiceEnum> {
    associatedtype ChoiceEnum: RawRepresentable where ChoiceEnum.RawValue: StringProtocol
    associatedtype HasConcreteActions: HasActions<ChoiceEnum>
}
// or ideally
protocol User {
    associatedtype HasConcreteActions: HasActions
    // but later on I'm blocked because I need to define it i.e. as HasActions<ActionsFooEnum>
}
```

The goal is to then use User and a "concrete" HasActions together.

```swift
protocol UserWithFooActions: User<ActionsFooEnum> where HasConcreteActions: HasFooAction {
    func hasBeenCalled()
    func hasBeenSeen()
}
```

But in the end when I try to use it on some class, it looks like it can't infer what HasConcreteActions is :/

```swift
class UserWithActions: UserWithActionFoo {
    var fooActions: (any HasConcreteActions)?

    func didCallMe() {
        fooActions?.action(.fooo)
    }
    
    func didTalkToMe() {
        fooActions?.action(.foo)
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the compiler still asks me for

```swift
    typealias ChoiceEnum = ActionsFooEnum
    typealias HasConcreteActions = HasActions<ActionsFooEnum>
    // the compiler then still asks me to define HasConcreteActions :o
```

Does anyone can indicate me if I'm doing something wrong, or if I try to do is not possible? Where is the bottleneck? Maybe the relationship can be defined differently?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your detailed approach, but can you tell us what you want to achieve, in one sentence?

Comment: *…the "concrete" Foo Action protocol would be defined as…* This is where you went sideways. Protocols are not concrete types. Protocols do not conform to themselves. You cannot conform a type to a protocol using a protocol as the associated type. You must provide an actual, concrete (struct, class, enum) type, not yet another protocol. But all of this is very over-complicated, and is going to slam into every limitation in the Swift type system. Don't start with a series of protocols. Start with concrete code and extract the protocols from algorithms that are repeated.

Comment: Since everything here is just wrapping `action`, you can get rid of most of this and replace it with a `(ChoiceEnum) -> Void` closure rather than a protocol. That approach will avoid the limitations Swift has with both higher-kinded types and generalized existentials. (It's also simpler.)